# Rails 4.2.5 can't hide routes after adding new collection route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model with only two actions: list the index (watch all changes since last check) and delete all the items in the table.

As such I define a new action for the delete (in config/routes.rb):

```
resources :changes do
    collection { delete 'delete_all' }
end
```

This works fine (after creating the delete_all action in the controller).

Next step is to restrict the routes that are exposed, because I only need index and the new one:

```
  resources :changes, :only => [ :index, :delete_all ]
```

Unfortunately, even with this second line, the resources aren't constrained at all.

If I don't define the new action delete_all, it does work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

resources :changes, :only => [ :index, :delete_all ], work with only curd action like [new,index,edit,show,destroy,create,update].
So rails resources: not allow to add custom action in ":only =>[]",and you will use with the collection.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found it. Actually Rails makes a difference between the "resourceful" and "non-resourceful" routes. The resource full ones are the 7 default ones and a lot of methods only work on those.

Finally I defined the routes in as following and this worked fine:

get 'changes/' => 'changes#index', as: 'changes'

delete 'changes/' => 'changes#delete_all', as: 'delete_all'